# Request_UnsupportedQuery: Filtering B2C users with domain name

Tags: filter, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-ad-b2c

We figured out finding way to list only B2C users by using filter. We tried to filter users with their B2C domain name like

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endswith(mail,'@b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com')
```

But this is not working out, tried different ways but same error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported Query.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-11-28T15:47:46",
            "request-id": "4171772d-05f8-4f97-97f9-f0965b3f46d3",
            "client-request-id": "d8a4aee6-4ba1-4f92-a26d-2b7bbbd54520"
        }
    }
}
```

Along with the list of B2C users, we want to get their count. There is no proper documentation regarding this.

Comment: Documentation about advanced queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got below results:***

I have these **existing users** in my Azure B2C tenant like below:

[image]

Now I ran the **same query** as you in [***Graph Explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)   and got **same error** as below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endswith(mail,'@b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com')
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, the b2c users where username is their **Gmail account** will also have **`UserPrincipalName`** that ends with
> @b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com.

If you want to fetch all b2c users, you can just sign in with **b2c user credentials** to [***Graph Explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)  and run the normal query without using $filter like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName
```

**Response:**

[image]

Note that, using `$count` parameter is **not** currently supported by *Azure AD B2C tenants* whereas you can get **users count** in normal Azure AD tenant with below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endswith(mail,'@tenant.onmicrosoft.com')&$orderby=userPrincipalName&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:** [List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-get-all-users-with-a-mail-that-ends-with-acontosocom-including-a-count-of-returned-objects-with-the-results-ordered-by-userprincipalname)

Answer (score 1):

The `endsWith` operator is supported only with advanced query parameters by `mail`, `otherMails`, `userPrincipalName`, and `proxyAddresses` properties.

These advanced query capabilities are not available by default but, you must also set the `ConsistencyLevel` header to `eventual` and use the `$count` query parameter with value `true`. The `ConsistencyLevel` header and `$count` are referred to as advanced query parameters.

When `$count=true` is used in the query than the response contains `@odata.count` parameter with number of the results for the requested query.

The query with advanced parameters:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endswith(mail,'@b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com')&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

Documentation:

[AAD advanced queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#support-for-filter-on-properties-of-azure-ad-directory-objects)